# Unnest a SQL column and count common features for two given elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a SQL table with 4 columns: `user_id, created_at, game_ids and id`.

`game_ids` is an array int[ ]. 
For some reason for the same values of `user_id, created_at and game_ids`, there are distinct ids as shown below.

```
userID      created_at      game_ids                                      id
147         13/9/2018       [559, 13, 21, 212]                            1
150         14/9/2018       [21, 559, 212]                                2
185         12/9/2018       [212, 21]                                     3
147         13/9/2018       [559, 13]                                     4
185         12/9/2018       [212, 21, 13, 559]                            5
136         13/9/2018       [559, 13, 212]                                6
150         10/9/2018       [21, 559, 13, 569, 212]                       7
```

I want to find for a given `game_id` say 559 how many other `game_ids` share the same player and the total number of player for each of those `game_ids`. The output would look something like below:

```
game_id   common users with 559    Total users
559            6                        6
13             5                        5
21             4                        5
212            5                        6
569            1                        1
```

Comment: What data type **exactly** is the column `game_ids`? The best thing would be if you can [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question

Comment: It is PostgreSQL and game_ids is an array.

Comment: What kind of array? `int[]`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, integers.